# Dockerizing spring boot application using JIB plugin

Tags: spring-boot, docker, jib

I am using maven jib plugin to dockerize my Spring boot based application.

https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin

```
<plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <resources>
                                        <resource>
                                            <directory>src/main/resources/static</directory>
                                        </resource>
                                    </resources>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/webapp/static</outputDirectory>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.9.13</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <from>
                                <image>${base.image}</image>
                            </from>
                            <to>
                                <image>${registry}/${repository}/${image}:${version}</image>
                            </to>
                            <extraDirectory>${project.build.directory}/webapp</extraDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
```

I do not have args or Entrypoint in the JIB plugin. I would like to control it thru the argument.

While running "mvn clean install", I see the below line in the logs.

```
Container entrypoint set to [java, -cp, /app/resources:/app/classes:/app/libs/*, com.test.Application]
```

I tried passing --spring.config.location as program arguments as below. But it is not picking my application.properties. I tried modifying the starting class name to check if it is working, but it is still taking com.test.Application. Looks like, it is not considering -c here.

> docker run -v
>   /local/path/config/:/secrets/
>   IMAGE:1.0
>   bash "java -cp /app/libs/*:/app/resources/:/app/classes/ -Xmx2g -Xms2g
>   com.test.Application
>   --spring.config.location=/secrets/application.yml"

Comment: How are you injecting the `/secrets/application.yml` into the container?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Jib to build your container image, the default entrypoint would be

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java", jib.container.jvmFlags, "-cp", "/app/resources:/app/classes:/app/libs/*", jib.container.mainClass]
```

Also jib use distroless image that contain only runtime dependencies. So you cannot run `bash` in your container.

This should do the job.

```
docker run -e "spring.config.location=/secrets/application.yml" -v /local/path/config/:/secrets/ IMAGE:1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Understands the problem , when using jib as maven plugin

then entryPoint to be passed inside container, but seems jib plugin didn't pick that up .

so below changes needs to be done for the argument access for the location :

```
           <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <to>
                    <image>image-url</image>
                </to>

                <container>
                    <creationTime>${maven.build.timestamp}</creationTime>
                    <mainClass>com.package.SpringBootMainClass</mainClass>
                    <args>
                        <arg>--spring.config.location=/demo/location/application.yml</arg>
                    </args>
                </container>

            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```